# still in trouble with MD5

Tags: c++, md5

I finished a implementation of MD5 algorithm in C++, but it doesn't work properly... My Hashes aren't correct.

Just for understanding:
If I try to Hash a File (64 byte) with MD5 hash algorithm the following have to happen:

```
//    512 Bit(data)     512 Bit(Padding)
//    -------------     ------------- 
//    |xxxxxxxxxxx|     |10000000|64|
//    -------------     -------------
//
//     1 - appended 1 Bit
//     0 - filled with zeros until 8 bytes before end of block
//    64 - 64 bit (8 Byte) representation of size of file
```

1st: MD5 algorithm with data block

2nd: create additional block with Padding

3rd: MD5 algorithm with Padding Block

Right?

Comment: oh....... DAMN.... i found the mistake.... the value for the 64 bit representation of the size of file must be in Bit, not Byte............. :) :) :)

so, in my case, the counter isn't 64. It has to be 64*8 (512).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the 64-Bit representation MUST be in Bits, not Bytes!
Therefore the counter, in my case, isn't 64. It is 64*8 = 512.